# Java Inner class listener access other inner class calling it

Tags: java, actionlistener, inner-classes

So I have this code :

```
public class TabTaches extends JPanel {
    //TabTaches Variables

    TabTaches() {
        // Constructor content
    }

    private class NouvelleTache extends JFrame {
        // Nouvelle Tache Variables

        NouvelleTache() {
            ecouteur = new Ecouteur();

            this.setTitle("Nouvelle tache");
            this.setSize(300, 200);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));

            annuler = new JButton("Annuler");

            annuler.addActionListener(ecouteur);

            this.add(annuler);
        }
    }

    private static class Ecouteur implements ActionListener {
        NouvelleTache nt;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(((AbstractButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Annuler")) {
                Something.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to manage `Something.dispose();`
I know you can access the outer class using `TabTaches.this.dispose();` but here what I want to close is `NouvelleTache`. Is there a way to do it?
Is it even right syntactically speaking or should I create a whole class for `NouvelleTache`? I thought of making it inner class because I only need it into `TabTaches`, but maybe I'm complicating too much here.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by separating Listeners for Outer Class and Inner Class, that way I can access My instance of nt with the method described above `TabTaches.this.dispose();`
I'm not really sure if this is right though, but it works.